# How to merge two or more trained weights?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I implemented a 5x5 Gomoku by CNN + DQN.
Here is the github link:
https://github.com/bokidigital/CNN_DQN_5x5_Gomoku

My problem is this code has no parallelization design. 
This means when running this code on an Intel Skylake server ( 2 CPU, 80 cores ), the CPU usage is just about 90%.

I think the idea CPU usage should be 8000% ( 80 cores ).

Since I have some customized rule in gaming ( not only neural network part which consumes GPU about 75% ), it consumes CPU and no parallelization.

My environment is:

```
Skylake CPU X 2

NVIDIA P100 X 2 ( only use 1 )

40GB RAM

Tensorflow 1.14.0

Keras

Python 3.7

Ubuntu 16.04
```

My idea is to run this program separately ( run many copies of this process in the different folder which then generates different weights ) then CPU usage could reach ideally to 8000% ( as long as many processes run at the same time )

Since it is the training process, it doesn't matter how each process trained their weights.

Q1. The problem is how to merge their results(the trained weights)? (A+B)/2?

Q2. It seems 1 GPU can only be used by 1 process, I tried to run 3 process at the same time, the GPU seems to hang.

Q3. If I disabled GPU, 80 core Skylake will faster than NVIDIA P100?

I expect to use more CPU usage to speed up this training process.
Since 5x5 agent trained with 5 days, I tested the same code but change grid size to 9x9, I estimated the training time needs 3 months.

Comment: merging models is called federated learning...

Comment: can we do it by keras command directly?